# exchange method in resttemplate throwing NullpointerException in case of error where postman is showing error details

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

When I am trying to hit a rest service I am getting data in case of success response but in case of any kind of exception I am getting only nullpointer exception where as per the contract service provider is sending proper error response as shown below(I verified through postman)

`responseEntity = template.exchange(eslMedicationPullUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);`

Error response in postman

```
{
    "httpCode": "408",
    "httpMessage": "TimeOut Error",
    "moreInformation": "TIME OUT ERROR FROM EDB Service TransactionID:45564854010000001c000000a98967e2682b000000000000"
}
```

Can somebody please advise what should I change so that I can get proper error response in case provider sends that.

Even I tried to pass a pojo having same attributes which are coming in error response to test and passed it but still got nullpointerexception

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
template.setErrorHandler(new RestInvocationErrorHandler());
          
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptorList = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
interceptorList.add(new LoggingClientHttpRequestInterceptor());
template.setInterceptors(interceptorList);

responseEntity = template.exchange(eslMedicationPullUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, ErrorResponse.class);
```

```
public class ErrorResponse {
    
  @JsonProperty("httpCode")
  private String httpCode = null;
         
  @JsonProperty("httpMessage")
  private String httpMessage = null;
         
  @JsonProperty("moreInformation")
  private String moreInformation = null;

}
```

Comment: Please share the response including headers from postman.